# How make a dynamically header field in ali manager wso2

Tags: header, wso2, wso2-api-manager, api-manager

I want to know how can I change the value of field in the header of the backend service dynamically

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use header mediator to manipulate the headers[1] in mediation extension[2]

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB500/Header+Mediator

[2] https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM200/Adding+Mediation+Extensions